# Angular 2 webpack websocket reference lost

Tags: angularjs, sockets, oop, websocket, webpack

I am trying to use websockets from my frontend. In the process I have attempted to connect to a URL with ngOnInit, which gives med 502 error - connection refused.

My problem is that when I try to call a function from either onError, onClose, onMessage or onOpen, I get "function not found". In the example code below I am simply trying to call a function called "connect" from either of the 4 mentioned socket functions:

```
onOpen() {
   console.log("Open!!")
 }


 onError(error) {
   console.log("Error !!!!");
   console.log(error);
 }

 onClose() {
   console.log("Closed!");
   this.connect();
 }

 onMessage(message) {
   console.log("Message!!");
   console.log(message);
 }


  ngOnInit(){
    this.ws = new WebSocket("wss://api.modusanitas.com/");
    this.ws.onerror = this.onError;
    this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
    this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
    this.ws.onclose = this.onClose;

  }

  connect() {
    console.log("Helo!")
  }
```

It seems like "this" reference is lost. Why is this, and how can I call functions like this correctly?

Comment: I cheat and use this autobind decorator: https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator